# trying to connect to nexus with python using nexuscli

Tags: python, api, command-line-interface, nexus

I am trying to connect to the server doing:

```
nexus_config = nexuscli.nexus_config.NexusConfig(username=NEXUS_USER,
                                                 password=NEXUS_PASSWORD,
                                                 url=NEXUS_URL,
                                                 x509_verify=True)
nexus_client = nexuscli.nexus_client.NexusClient(config=nexus_config)
print(nexus_client.repositories.list)
```

But, I get the error:

```
nexuscli.exception.NexusClientConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my_site.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

https://nexus3-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nexuscli.html#module-nexuscli.nexus_config

checking the URL using the API endpoing with the requests library and setting `validate=False` I get a warning and does work.

So I change my code to: `x509_verify=True` hoping that the same from requests will happen that i will be getting warnings but instead i got.

Is there something I am missing? or maybe there is a bug in the library?
thanks guys.

```
nexuscli.exception.NexusClientAPIError: <exception str() failed>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception: `NexusClientAPIError`. According to the [documents](https://nexus3-cli.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/api/modules.html):

> exception nexuscli.exception.NexusClientAPIError Bases: Exception
>
> **Unexpected response from Nexus service.**

I think your code is fine and the issue with `x.509` certificate is resolved and the problem might be on the server's side.

Comment: You are right, i can print nexus_client.http.server_version and that doesnt call the api just grab the information from the __init__